# Just the Treble Clef (Arabic music)

Tags: theory, piano, digital-piano

When searching for Arabic music I noticed that there is no grand staff, just the treble clef.  I am searching in the internet as to why this is the case.  The explanation is that Western music relies on harmony (a couple of notes played together) while Arabic music relies mainly on melody (notes played one after another).  My question is :

1. Can we transform any harmonic music to melody?
2. If the above is not always true, is there a site just for melodic music sheet?

Comment: It sounds like you're looking for piano versions of Arabic music. Is that correct?

Comment: @Aaron true, i have downloaded the famous ones but finding them seems harder than western music sheets.

Comment: "a site just for melodica": what do you mean?  Are you interested in a site with Arabic or European melodies (and, if so, which)?  Are you interested in a site with music intended to be played on the [melodica](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Melodica)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can we transform any harmonic music to melody?

Most European music that has harmony uses the harmony to accompany a melody, so yes, we can play the melody by itself.  In fact, you can find song books of European music that contain only the melody.  These often have *chord symbols* that indicate the harmony without using a grand staff, but that is by no means universal.

Furthermore, there are compositions in the European classical repertoire for only a solo instrument such as a violin or flute.  These compositions will also use only the treble clef.

> is there a site just for melodica?

I'm not exactly sure what you mean by this, so I'll await a response to the questions I asked in the comments above.

Comment: i did not meant melodica to refer to  the instrument but for melody as in one note after the other, if you know a site that give melodic sheet music that would be great to include in the answer, thanks, i will fix the post.